# How to implement a custom monitoring process without using a test runner?

Tags: .net, teamcity

I have a build and deployment configuration that pushes out a series of apps/services to a test environment, all fine. After deploying I start the services running and kick off a workflow. This workflow is not run within the context of a test or test runner but I want to be able to report its progress back to the agent, ideally by querying a log or database and reporting errors back to TC. I then need to signal TC that the workflow is complete, either with success or failure.

What's the easiest way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Write your own checker that checks the logs or the database, you can write to standard out that will go in the TeamCity log.  If error exit with an error code Teamcity will notice your process exited with error.